# Qt How to set the values of ComboBox based on the selected option in another ComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, combobox, qt-creator

I am trying to build an application which needs to get various inputs from the user. The input choices vary depending on the previous inputs chosen.
Something like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfzwc.png)

So if the user selects the Number option the right combobox should display numerical values.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU5Gb.png)

Similarly if Alphabet is chosen it should display A,B,C,etc.

So I need the lists to be dynamic for all drop downs. How do I do this?

I am using **Qt Creator** for the above. Below is the code of the .ui file for the first combobox:

```
widget class="QGroupBox" name="gbType">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>60</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>281</width>
      <height>81</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>12</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="layoutDirection">
     <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">border: 1px solid gray;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string extracomment="Type"/>
    </property>
    <widget class="QComboBox" name="cbType">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>30</y>
       <width>241</width>
       <height>27</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="editable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Number</string>
      </property>
     </item>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Alphabet</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </widget>
   </widget>
```

For the second combobox:

```
<widget class="QGroupBox" name="gbCommand">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>450</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>281</width>
      <height>81</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>12</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="layoutDirection">
     <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">border: 1px solid gray;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
    <property name="flat">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="checkable">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <widget class="QComboBox" name="cbCommand">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>30</y>
       <width>241</width>
       <height>27</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="editable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="currentText">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>1</string>
      </property>
     </item>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>2</string>
      </property>
     </item>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>3</string>
      </property>
     </item>
    </widget>
   </widget>
```

PS: This is just a sample design therefore I am using the Numbers, Alphabets as example. Please don't suggest UI changes to accommodate the requirement as that will be out of scope of what I am doing.

Edit: There are multiple drop-downs that need to be populated based on the previous inputs; not just two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can connect the currentIndexChanged() signal of the first combobox to a slot that checks whether the current selection is "Numbers" or "Alphabets" and based on what is selected instantiates a QComboBox of the right type for the second one and replaces it.

Another option is tho place all the various comboboxes for "Command" in a QStackedWidget and then on `currentIndexChanged()` from the first combobox you check what the current selection is and switch the QStackedWidget to the page containing the matching Command combobox.

Comment: Will the second method work in case of more than 2 drop-downs i.e. a 3rd drop down needs to be populated using the values selected in the first two?

Comment: I don't see why not. Just hook the third up to the signal from the first two, check the value of both and pick the right one for the third.

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on how to implement the first solution? I am very new to Qt and not familiar with the concept of slots. Do you mean by using the 'Signals and slot editor' at the bottom of Qt Creator?